# Android app which easily lets you create your own, local wiki on your phone

Tags: android, wiki

I'm looking for an app which lets you create your own, local wiki on your Android phone so you can add and edit articles the same easy and user-friendly way you're used from the Wikipedia.org site.

During my research I stumbled upon the app [AndTidWiki](http://mgsimon.de/android/andtidwiki/), but it is everything else than user-friendly since it requires setting up a whole server manually. I don't think I need this solved server-style since I don't need any other user accounts than me. A simple database app should do I guess, but it seems I am too dumb to find one which is capable of linking articles via labeled sublinks within the text.

So, does such an app exist? If yes, how is it called, how much does it cost and is there maybe a free alternative?

**EDIT**: If it is only possible via server — Is there an (at least partly) automated solution?

Comment: I don't think it is possible without setting up a local server. On a server with PHP you could run [MediaWiki](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/MediaWiki).

Comment: Okay, so the obvious need for a server leads to the following question: Is there an easy or at least partly automatized way to set one up?

Comment: Take a look at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ru.kslabs.ksweb

Comment: Thanks, but that's shareware and only a 5-day trial... I downloaded Palapa Web Server ( https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.alfanla.android.pws ), do you think it is possible with this, too?

Comment: You can use the Paw Server: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.fun2code.android.pawserver
 It's free, and if you install the php plugin, you'll be able to run a wiki, for example lionwiki-t2t (if you copy the files into /sdcard/paw/html). It's working fine for me (even though I use the other solution described below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend to use a "classic" wiki on a PHP server. If you choose wisely, you can use a wiki with no SQL database, and synchronise the data between your server and your phone (or directly edit online). It means you'll be able to edit the text files of your wiki with any of the 3000 text editor available for android. It's easier to edit a local txt file rather than editing a form in a web browser, especially when it's from a phone.

To set up the wiki, I'd recommend lionwiki-t2t or dokuwiki (https://www.dokuwiki.org/)
To set up the sharing of your data, I'd recommend owncloud (http://owncloud.org/). With the owncloud android app, you can edit them online, but if you prefer to only deal with local files, you can synchronise with this good app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=dk.tacit.android.foldersync.full

For example you can synchronise every 30 minutes or 1 hour. When you're not using your phone, you can update your wiki from a web browser. For linking articles you just surround a name with []. Or course it won't work like that in a simple text editor but the use for it depends on your final needs.

I've developped "lionwiki-t2t", based on "lionwiki" with a special syntax (txt2tags). You can find it there:

http://wiki.txt2tags.org/demos/lionwiki-t2t

I'm using it everyday to keep my notes. It involves setting up a few things but it's not that difficult.

A more complete description for setting all this up is there:
[http://wiki.txt2tags.org/demos/lionwiki-t2t/index.php?page=help.en#*Synchronize*](http://wiki.txt2tags.org/demos/lionwiki-t2t/index.php?page=help.en#_Synchronize_)

If you only need a local wiki, you can also try this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hufs.dislab.anywrite2

There is also this, which is using dropbox, it may worth trying:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.janwillemboer.ema

(for my needs I want to use my wiki offline and synchronise it regularly so I prefer my solution...)

Comment: The last link perfectly fits my needs, thank you. I will give your solution a try, though.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple wiki-style editors available, which you can find listed e.g. in [this overview](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=25). Depending on which wiki-style you prefer, you can chose between [Mediawiki](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=25#group_106) (as used on e.g. Wikipedia) and [Markdown](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=25) (as used e.g. here at Stack Exchange) based apps.

#### Mediawiki style editors

Though not updated for a while, in this section **[WikiMind](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.sweetrain.wikimind)** seems to be a good candidate:

- works completely onboard (i.e. no server connection required)
- files are stored on your SD card
- supports links, lists, even images, and more
- of course you can link between multiple documents
- if you're working with Windows or Linux on your desktop, you can even use the very same files (sync'd via Dropbox, or using *FolderSync*, or any other sync option) with the compatible [ZIM](http://zim-wiki.org/) application
- [Free version](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.sweetrain.wikimind) to test if it fits your needs; [full version](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.sweetrain.wikimind.pro) for ~EUR 2 / ~USD 3

[image: WikiMind source mode] [image: WikiMind view mode]
<sup>WikiMind: Source (left) and rendered (right; source: *Google Play*; click images for larger variants)</sup>

#### Markdown style editors

Here I might point you to the **[Ema Personal Wiki](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.janwillemboer.ema)**. Again, not the most up-to-date app in this section – but fully free (even open-source), and meeting your criteria (where others I know lack the one or other):

- links to external web sites and internal documents
- Markdown support
- pages stored on your device
- Dropbox integration to sync with its Windows pendant

[image: Ema View] [image: Ema Dropbox]
<sup>Ema: View a document, Dropbox settings (source: *Google Play*, click images for larger variants)</sup>

Again, for more alternatives you might check the links I indicated in the beginning of my post; but these two candidates should do what you want.