# Personal wiki with a very good android app

Tags: android, web-apps, cms, web, wiki

I'm looking for a personal wiki for use as a private knowledge base and for advanced note taking on the go that I can host on my webserver for use by a very small number of people. The most important factor is that it must have a **great android app** and ideally "official".
It needs to be , be actively developed and well established. The most important factor is that it must have a great offline android app and ideally "official".

It should also have the following properties:

- **FOSS**
- Low maintenance (like wordpress - automatic updates or just a few clicks)
- reasonably secure (**passwords** and captchas)
- Simple, mainstream technology and infrastructure (just runs on linux, no obscure, hipster programming language, files preferred over databases)
- **Wysiwyg editor**
- **overall well established and actively developed**

I have been browsing https://www.wikimatrix.org but haven't quite found what I need. I like DokuWiki, but it has no usable App. Same with Mediawiki. Zim looks great, but I'd have to sync the notebook files with something like dropbox - also again no app.

I open to suggestions even if not all my criteria are met. The ones in bold are the most important to me.

Comment: The whole point of a wiki is that it is browser based.

Comment: Is it? Regardless that doesn't mean that there can't be a wiki with a good app.

Comment: Perhaps this question is similar? https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3455/android-app-which-easily-lets-you-create-your-own-local-wiki-on-your-phone

Comment: On Wikimatrix’s compare tool, look for the “mobile friendly” row.

Comment: Thanks, I'm starting to think DokuWiki might be the best choice after all, with a webview for android.

Comment: I played with DokuWiki some years back and really liked it.